# Uncaught Error: Component app-check has not been registered yet [For reactjs]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-app-check

While developing my react app, I tried to setup `appCheck` functionality from Firebase. The browser is giving output as shown in the title of the question. My `firebase-config.js` file is as shown:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
const { initializeAppCheck, ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider } = require("firebase/app-check");

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APPID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENTID
}

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
initializeAppCheck(app, {
  provider: new ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider(process.env.REACT_APP_RECAPTCHAENTERPRISE),

  // Optional argument. If true, the SDK automatically refreshes App Check
  // tokens as needed.
  isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true
});
```

[image: The output of the chrome inspect element]

I have tried to change imports, changing site keys and yet none of them works for me.

I expect that the app gets registered and can be browsable.

Comment: Did you remember to turn on AppCheck and register the reCaptcha provider in the firebase console?

Comment: Did that but nothing solved unfortunately.